# How to remove GMail label - Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-api

I want to remove the label "Followup" from each message that is placed back in the inbox. I have tried several things, but still without success. I hope someone can help me or point me in the right direction. The function concerned is:

```
function moveToInbox(page) {
  GmailApp.moveThreadsToInbox(page);
//  GmailApp.markThreadsUnread(page);
//  GmailApp.starMessages(page)
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FollowUp");
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var coupleOfMessages = firstThread.getMessages().slice(0, 10);
  GmailApp.starMessages(coupleOfMessages);
  label.removeFromThread(firstThread);
}
```

The entire script is:

```
function getLabelName(i, labelSuffixString) {
  return "FollowUp/" + i + labelSuffixString;
}

function setup() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    GmailApp.createLabel(getLabelName(i, "days"));
    GmailApp.createLabel(getLabelName(i, "weeks"));
  }
  GmailApp.createLabel("FollowUp");
}

function moveToInbox(page) {
  GmailApp.moveThreadsToInbox(page);
//  GmailApp.markThreadsUnread(page);
//  GmailApp.starMessages(page)
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FollowUp");
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
  var coupleOfMessages = firstThread.getMessages().slice(0, 10);
  GmailApp.starMessages(coupleOfMessages);
  label.removeFromThread(firstThread);
}

function cleanOldFollowUpLabels() {
  var searchString = "-label:inbox label:FollowUp";
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    searchString += " -label:" + getLabelName(i, "days");
    searchString += " -label:" + getLabelName(i, "weeks");
  }
  searchString = searchString.replace(RegExp("/", "g"), "-");
  Logger.log("cleanOldFollowUpLabels() Search String:");
  Logger.log(searchString);
  var followUpLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FollowUp");  
  var page = null;
  // Get threads in "pages" of 100 at a time
  while(!page || page.length == 100) {
    page = GmailApp.search(searchString, 0, 100);
    Logger.log("found: " + page.length);
    if (page.length > 0)
      followUpLabel.removeFromThreads(page);   
  }
}

function update(labelSuffixString) {
  var oldLabel, newLabel, page;
  var followUpLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FollowUp");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    newLabel = oldLabel;
    oldLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(getLabelName(i, labelSuffixString));
    page = null;
    // Get threads in "pages" of 100 at a time
    while(!page || page.length == 100) {
      page = oldLabel.getThreads(0, 100);
      if (page.length > 0) {
        followUpLabel.addToThreads(page);
        if (newLabel) {
          // Move the threads into "today’s" label
          newLabel.addToThreads(page);
        } else {
          moveToInbox(page);
        }     
        // Move the threads out of "yesterday’s" label
        oldLabel.removeFromThreads(page);
        // Wait for a minute to prevent timeout errors
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
      }  
    }
  }
}

function dailyUpdate() {
  update("days");
}
function weeklyUpdate() {
  update("weeks");
}
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you are seeing? What happens when you run the code? What is the function you are executing ? Also, can you use the execution transcript to see what is happening and debug.

Comment: This is the error message I get: Function:dailyUpdate Error Message:
ReferenceError: "FollowUp" is not defined. (line 36, file "Code") → I think I have changed followUp.removeFromThread(firstThread) into label.removeFromThread(firstThread)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wanted to remove "FollowUp" from all threads, you could use `label.deleteLabel()`. But since you're just interested in taking that label off of the threads you're restoring to the Inbox, you need to loop through them.

```
function moveToInbox(threadArray) {
  GmailApp.moveThreadsToInbox(threadArray);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("FollowUp");
  for (var i=0; i< threadArray.length; i++) {
    threadArray[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

Comment: will give this a try! thanks. have you tried the script yourself? it is quite useful to 'Snooze' messages for later actions.

Comment: I have added a line before your suggested line with "threadArray[i].starMessages(label);" - I get an error message for this line saying "TypeError: Cannot find function starMessages in object GmailThread. (line 42, file "Code")" -- how can I add a star to each message being moved to the inbox?

Comment: I did a test and it worked! Thanks a lot. If you have any idea how to add a star to the message being moved to the inbox, or make it unread, or mark it important, please share it with me. I have tried several things but not successfully.

Comment: Read the documentation for [GmailThread](http://goo.gl/gQ2xib) and [GmailMessage](http://goo.gl/KoXYIr) to make sure you're selecting methods that apply to one or the other Class. For instance, [GmailThread.markUnread()](http://goo.gl/TvVT1H) or [GmailThread.markImportant()](http://goo.gl/foOkx2) could go right after `removeLabel()`, as they operate on a Thread. A star, however, is applied to a message by [GmailMessage.star()](http://goo.gl/aRL6Zm), so you'd have to add another loop to go through messages in each thread and star them individually.

Comment: mm.. tried it using GmailThread.markUnread();, but I got this error: "ReferenceError: "GmailThread" is not defined. (line 43, file "Code")

Comment: @Mogsdad how can we removed pre-defined labels , like Inbox label from an email thread?