# Gmail Script: search then move to inbox, remove label

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

**The goal:**
Make Label1 labelled emails return to the inbox, and remove Label2 from that email.

This is what I have so far:

```
function _forceInbox() {
 var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label1");
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label: LABEL2 is:starred OR label:Not-Done');
   for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    label.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
      threads[i].moveToInbox();
  }
}
```

I got this using :
[How to remove GMail label - Google Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846457/how-to-remove-gmail-label-google-apps-script)

I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot call method "removeFromThread" of null. (line 8, file "myfile")
What does this mean?

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Okay! Answered my own question.! I added an 's'

That was it. removeFromThreads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to add an 's' I wish I had known before all this hassle.

"removefromthreads"
http://googlescriptreference.com/removefromthreadsthreads/